# Visual Basic 6.0 Case Statement

Tags: vb6

This little piece of code is supposed to fire off and give me the correct variable
but no matter what is in the variable "numericDay", the Variable "suffix" gives me
"th". i don't see why it wouldn't change when the value of "numericDay changes
both are string variables.

```
    Select Case numericDay
            Case numericDay = "1" Or "21" Or "31"
                 suffix = "st"
            Case numericDay = "2" Or "22"
                 suffix = "nd"
            Case numericDay = "3" Or "23"
                 suffix = "rd"
            Case Else
             suffix = "th"

    End Select
```

Comment: @Slaks they are both string variables. i thought i typed that but i think my original question got chopped down to size. no matter and no worries, i have seen the error in my syntax thanks to nybbler's answer.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You've written your select incorrectly.  Try the following:

```
    Select Case numericDay
            Case "1", "21", "31"
                 suffix = "st"
            Case "2", "22"
                 suffix = "nd"
            Case "3", "23"
                 suffix = "rd"
            Case Else
                 suffix = "th"
    End Select
```

For future reference: http://www.vb6.us/tutorials/learn-if-else-and-select-statements-vb6

Comment: +1 For future reference you could also try the manual http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa266274(v=VS.60).aspx

Answer (score 8):

According to [the msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/cy37t14y%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) you should have written it like this:

```
Select Case numericDay
        Case "1", "21", "31"
             suffix = "st"
        Case "2", "22"
             suffix = "nd"
        Case "3", "23"
             suffix = "rd"
        Case Else
         suffix = "th"
End Select
```

Answer (score 5):

`"2" Or "22"` will do a bytewise or with 2 and 22, which corresponds to 22.

Answer (score 1):

---

i think this is the correct logic...

```css
Select Case Right(Text1.Text, 1)
Case "1"
 Label3.Caption = "st"
Case "2"
 Label3.Caption = "nd"
 Case "3"
 Label3.Caption = "rd"
 Case ""
 Label3.Caption = ""
 Case Else
 Label3.Caption = "th"
 End Select
```

Answer (score 0):

You've written your select incorrectly. Try the following

Eg: display day according to the number which is entered.

```
public function day_display(day as Integer) as String
   select case day
        case 1: day_display = "Sunday"
        case 2: day_display = "Monday"
        case 3: day_display = "Tuesday"
        case 4: day_display = "Wednesday"
        case 5: day_display = "Thursday"
        case 6: day_display = "Friday"
        case 7: day_display = "Saturday"
        case else: day_display = "Wrong entry."
   end select
end function
```

day_display(1) will return "Sunday"